# Sequelize update - balance

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't figure out how I can subtract 50 from the amount of 100
Using sequelize mysql.
What.How do I do it?

```
var us = await User.findOne({ where: { userID: ctx.from.id } })
await us.update({balance: -50?})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the current balance in your code while updating:

```
var us = await User.findOne({ where: { userID: ctx.from.id } })
await us.update({balance: us.balance - 50})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the increment/decrement instance methods provided by sequelize like below:

```
var us = await User.findOne({ where: { userID: ctx.from.id } });
await us.decrement({ balance: {by: 50} });
```